# How to make a text flash in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know flashing text is banned at many places but still as my client requires it, I need to flash one line of text using HTML, JavaScript which ever is feasible. I would like the text to appear and disappear within seconds and continue this cycle.

I know text-decoration:blink in CSS can do this but it only works in FireFox, Opera. And I need this to work in all browsers Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE. I have searched and tried a lot of Javascript codes but none seem to be working.

So any one who knows how to do this, please post a working version of code which does flash the text in all browsers.

Comment: Sounds like you might need the server-side blink tag! http://cheese.blartwendo.com/web21-demo.html

Comment: @DanBreen Just be aware it may not work in Web 2.2

Comment: @Widor whats Web 2.2?, and why may it not work?

Comment: @david I was being sarcastic - see Dan Breen's link which is a spoof/joke - it uses an AJAX server request for every blink on/off (clearly overkill).

Comment: -1 for lacking the balls to the client he is wrong.

Comment: @Raynos - some clients cannot be convinced and in the end if this is what he or she wants that's what ivn needs to deliver.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="Foo">Blink</div>
```

With the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('Foo');
    setInterval(function() {
        f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000);

});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7XRcJ/

If you're not using jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('Foo');
    setInterval(function() {
        f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000);

}, false);
```

Various browsers have different ways of binding event handlers, so I would strongly suggest using some sort of cross-browser library for this sort of thing if possible.

You can also try using the onload event in the body tag.  Here's a full example that I've tested in FF and IE7:

```js
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('Foo');
   setInterval(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="blink();">

<div id="Foo">Blink</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I only tested in Firefox.  Do you get an error or anything, or does it just not blink?

Answer (score 35):

```js
var blink_speed = 1000; // every 1000 == 1 second, adjust to suit
var t = setInterval(function () {
    var ele = document.getElementById('myBlinkingDiv');
    ele.style.visibility = (ele.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden');
}, blink_speed);
```

```html
<div id="myBlinkingDiv">Hello World, blinking is back!</div>
```

I feel dirty.

Comment: ? @david jsfiddle is perfect for this sort of thing, allows everyone to check it out without hassle.

Comment: @Loktar i was having a digg at one of comments chris posted

Comment: ... yes, in fact, it does work, as you can see in the jsFiddle. If it isn't working, you've done something wrong. Use jsFiddle to post a sample of your code and I can take a look.

Comment: Ok all the down-votes on everyone's answer is kinda lame.  People are just trying to help here.

Comment: @ivn: Make sure you have javascript turned on and you are not using `lynx` for browsing. And if you want members to help you then try to provide more information: Fiddle snippet doesn't work? Or your own code based on the sample? If it is your own, then where is the code we can have a look at? What browser are you using?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: +1 Definitely agree! People want to help and are getting downvoted without any reason. To downvoter: At least provide comment with downvote explanation so they can see what they did wrong. They can at least learn something.

Comment: The downvotes are pretty over the top on this cheesy question, although, I will say that the answers that use jQuery (considering the question isn't tagged with jQuery) are technically inaccurate - the code will not work if OP were to copy/paste it. And, jQuery *is* horrible. Downvote material, probably not, but still...  That said, @ivn, every answer here **does** work.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - totally agree.

Answer (score 5):

if you use jQuery you can do something like

```
<div id="msg"> <strong>This will blink</strong> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" />
    function blink(selector){
        $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                blink(this);
            });
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        blink('#msg');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [**this snippet**](http://jsbin.com/iyoniq/2/edit#javascript,html,live).

```
function blinkIt() {
  var blinks = document.getElementsByClassName("blink");
  for(var i = 0, l = blinks.length; i < l; i++){
    var blink = blinks[i];
    var visiblity = blink.style.visibility;
    blink.style.visibility = visiblity == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
   }
 }

setInterval(blinkIt, 500 /* blinking interval in ms */);
```

This solution will make **all** elements with class `blink` blinking.

EDIT: Tested on Firefox, Chrome and IE9.

Comment: @ivn: the snippet is not working for you? because it is fully functional so you probably did something wrong. Also make sure all elemnts you want to blink have **class** set to `blink`.

Comment: I think this code is pretty elegant, straight forward and minimalistic. I don't understand why it has only been voted up once. I love it.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript and the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API)!

```js
elem.animate([{opacity:0},{opacity:1}],{duration:300,iterations:Infinity})
```

```html
<h1 id="elem">WTF</h1>
```

---

Using [CSS @keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)!

```css
#elem {
  animation: blink 0.3s infinite
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="elem">WTF</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do this then you can use the blink plugin for jQuery

http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.blink').blink(); // default is 500ms blink interval.
        //$('.blink').blink({delay:100}); // causes a 100ms blink interval.
});
```

Comment: If they're running jQuery already then I don't see anything wrong with this to be honest.

Comment: it's 20000 lines even if you have jQuery?

Comment: Ah fair enough. In that case I withdraw my answer.

Comment: Actually I'm going to throw this back in. It might be over the top but it'll work.

Comment: Yes, leave it here. It might be not suitable for ivn, but this answer can be helpful for somebody else looking for the solution of the same problem in the future.

Comment: To be fair, jQuery isn't 20,000 lines.. It's just one line..  One.... _really_ big line..

Answer (score 0):

You could make the text blink via jquery. Put the text you want to blink in a `<blink>` tag and the javascript below will make it blink. Increase the duration below if it blinks too fast.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function(){
      $('blink').each(function(){
        $(this).css('visibility' , $(this).css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden')
      });
    }, 250);
</script>
<blink>Text to blink here</blink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #blink{
            color:black;opacity:1;font-size:3EM;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blink">
        Poop
    </div>
    <script>
        var ops,blink=document.getElementById('blink');
        ops=1
        setInterval(function (){
            ops = (ops < 1) ? 1:0;
            blink.style.opacity=ops;
        },500);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('Foo');
   setInterval(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="blink();">

<div id="Foo">Blink</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

JS:

```
setInterval(blinkFunc, 200)

blinkFunc = function () {
  var selector = '#some-selector';

  jQuery(selector + ':visible').addClass('hidden');
  jQuery(selector + ':not(:visible)').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

That's probably the most cross-browser. Note that Webkit does some crazy stuff with visibility so it might be easier to just change the color.

Comment: I am afraid, none of your solutions are entirely working for me. One or two of it works in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome Safari.