# Create a text fade in/fade out using strictly JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display text on my HTML webpage that will basically "flash" by fading in, and back out constantly with a 1 second break between the animation. This has to be done strictly using JS, no CSS, no jQuery.

My idea was the following:

```
 *Creating a div strictly for the text

 *Creating a function to house our JS

 *Create the fade animation by adjusting div style.opacity
```

I've completed this perfectly using CSS, I just have absolutely no idea where to start in terms of strictly JS.

Here's what I did in CSS:

```
    @keyframes fadeIn { 
  from { opacity: 0; } 
}
.play {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

Can someone point me in a good direction of what I should be doing if im only using JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a text flash in html/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360130/how-to-make-a-text-flash-in-html-javascript)

Comment: You can't, CSS (or a style object) is needed, HTML doesn't contain any currently valid formatting attributes which could emulate animations, and JS alone is not capable to show anything on a page.

Comment: Is it just the css stylesheet you can't use? Can inline styles be set with javascript?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `setinterval` function and inside the function toggle the css to the text 
here is the code I have tried. Hope it helps you.

```js
var speed = 1000; 
var t = setInterval(function(){
  var slideSource = document.getElementById('textnode');
  slideSource.classList.toggle('fade');
}, speed);
```

```css
#textnode {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s; 
}

#textnode.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="textnode">Sample Text</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use css stylesheets but can use inline css..

```js
var opacity = 1;
var change = -0.1;
var blinky = document.getElementById('blinky');
setInterval(function() { 
  blinky.style.color='hsla(210, 100%, 50%, '+opacity+')';
  if (opacity < -0.9) {
    change = 0.1;
    opacity = 0;
  } else if (opacity > 0.9) {
    change = -0.1;
  }
  opacity = opacity + change;
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="blinky">Blinky</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/t3dz62ck/