# Text fade left to right using JavaScript and CSS only

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make my own alert for my stream and for that I need to get the text from streamlabs (i think getElementById will work) and then I have to fade the text (or the entire HTML tag) from left to right.

I can make the text fade away by using CSS but I can t make it like this image.
[image: text fade]

What should I do?

Comment: Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510456/7921804
it may help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use this, If need more help tell me.

```css
.image-border{
position: fixed;
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
background-color: gray;
display: block;
}
.image-text-center{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 25px;
}
.image-text-center::after{
content:'';
position: absolute;
display: block;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 0;
height: 25px; /* size of font-size text parent */
background-color: gray;
transition: all 2500ms linear;
box-shadow: 8px 0 15px 10px gray;
}
.image-border:hover .image-text-center::after{
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-border" >

<div class="image-text-center">HELLO WORLD!!</div>

</div>
```

I appreciate if my answer helps you ,accept and vote up it;

Comment: Also you can add animation instead of using hover

Comment: actually, it's a clever trick to do this but to be honest I need a transparent background, and it's not transparent ...   btw ...you did a good job.